# High CPU usage on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, laptop, cpu-load

I can not use Ubuntu on my laptop on batteries as it has very high CPU usage even when no application is running! 
Therefore, the charge drops fast(I always hear the cpu fan sound when I am in Ubuntu). Why?? what is the reason and why it is not solved by the developers? anybody have the same experience?

My system:
Dell Inspiron N5110
CPU: i7 2.0
Ram: 6g

Comment: Please run top in a terminal to see what process is using CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Inspiron 5521, 4G RAM and all is ok. The CPU usage depends on the number of precesses you have on, an the memory it needs.
The fan is another history in ubuntu. I can tell you in my laptop it improves much better cleaning fan and harware if you dare (sometimes very necessary).

Another thing you can try is to suspend session and start again (not reboot). Also works turn off your screen and wait some seconds, for this you can try:

sleep 1; DISPLAY=:0.0 xset s activate

Hope can help you.